# Unrecognized Resource link "Fixed in Changeset"

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm migrating Work items from a single project from TFS2017 to DevOps using the [azure-devops-migration-tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools) tool, and it's throwing a runtime exception when migrating a specific work item with the following message:

> Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in

When I look at the source work item in TFS, I don't even see a link of that type:
[image: TFS work item screenshot]

Is there something I can do to skip those bad link types, or is this a bug in the migration software that needs fixed?

Here's the full stack trace:

```
[09:08:55 INF] Application Starting
...
[09:08:55 INF] ===============================================================================
[09:08:55 INF] Azure DevOps Migration Tools [Object Model]
[09:08:55 INF] v11.6.4.0
[09:08:55 INF] naked Agility with Martin Hinshelwood
[09:08:55 INF] ===============================================================================
[09:08:55 INF] Telemetry Note: We use Application Insights to collect telemetry on performance & feature usage for the tools to help our developers target features. This data is tied to a session ID that is generated and shown in the logs. This can help with debugging.
[09:08:55 INF] Start Time: 10/15/2020 09:08:55
[09:08:55 INF] Running with args: execute
[09:08:55 INF] OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
[09:08:55 INF] Version: 11.6.4.0
[09:08:55 DBG] Hosting starting
[09:08:55 INF] Config Found, creating engine host
[09:08:56 INF] Creating Migration Engine e696782e-f0ed-4928-a49d-25591ed7744d
[09:08:56 DBG] Starting with arguments: MigrationTools-11.6.4\migration.exe execute -c configs\Websites.json
[09:08:56 DBG] Starting with arguments: MigrationTools-11.6.4\migration.exe execute -c configs\Websites.json
[09:08:56 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[09:08:56 INF] Hosting environment: Production
[09:08:56 INF] Content root path: C:\Projects\DevOpsMigrations
[09:08:56 INF] Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[09:08:56 DBG] Hosting started
[09:08:56 INF] ProcessorContainer: Of 1 configured Processors only 1 are enabled
[09:08:56 INF] ProcessorContainer: Adding Processor WorkItemMigrationContext
[09:08:56 INF] Logging has been configured and is set to: Information.
[09:08:56 INF]                               Max Logfile: Verbose.
[09:08:56 INF]                               Max Console: Debug.
[09:08:56 INF]                  Max Application Insights: Error.
[09:08:56 INF] The Max log levels above show where to go look for extra info. e.g. Even if you set the log level to Verbose you will only see that info in the Log File, however everything up to Debug will be in the Console.
[09:08:56 INF] Beginning run of 1 processors
[09:08:56 INF] Processor: WorkItemMigration
[09:08:56 INF] Migration Context Start: WorkItemMigration
[09:08:56 INF] Starting
[09:08:56 INF] MigrationClient: Access granted
[09:09:00 INF] MigrationClient: Access granted
[09:09:02 INF] Found 93 work item fields.
[09:09:02 INF] Found 'ReflectedWorkItemId' in this project, proceeding.
[09:09:02 INF] Migrating all Nodes before the work item run.
[09:09:03 INF]  Processing Node: \<REDACTED>\Iteration\Iteration 1, start date: null, finish date: null
[09:09:03 INF]  Processing Node: \<REDACTED>\Iteration\Iteration 2, start date: null, finish date: null
[09:09:04 INF]  Processing Node: \<REDACTED>\Iteration\Iteration 3, start date: null, finish date: null
[09:09:04 INF]  Processing Node: \<REDACTED>\Iteration\Release 1, start date: null, finish date: null
[09:09:04 INF]  Processing Node: \<REDACTED>\Iteration\Release 1\Sprint 1, start date: null, finish date: null
[09:09:08 INF] Replay all revisions of 16 work items?
[09:09:08 INF] Found target project as <REDACTED>
[09:09:08 INF] [FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget] is enabled. Searching for work items that have already been migrated to the target...
[09:09:17 INF] !! After removing all found work items there are 16 remaining to be migrated.
[09:09:17 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Work Item has 2 revisions and revision migration is set to True
[09:09:17 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Found 2 revisions to migrate on  Work item:683
[09:09:18 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null |  Processing Revision [1]
[09:09:18 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null |  Saved TargetWorkItem 107. Replayed revision 1 of 2
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null |  Processing Revision [2]
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null |  Saved TargetWorkItem 107. Replayed revision 2 of 2
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Links 2 | LinkMigrator:True
[09:09:19 INF] Migrating link for 683 of type Hyperlink
[09:09:19 INF] Migrating link for 683 of type ExternalLink
[09:09:19 INF] Creating new ExternalLink on 107
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | ...FAILED to Save
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId (ReflectedWorkItemId) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.FinishDate (Finish Date) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate (Start Date) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild (Integration Build) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank (Stack Rank) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority (Priority) | 2
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy (Closed By) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate (Closed Date) | 10/15/2020 09:09:19
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy (Resolved By) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate (Resolved Date) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy (Activated By) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate (Activated Date) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate (State Change Date) | 10/15/2020 09:09:19
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity (Activity) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork (Completed Work) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate (Original Estimate) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork (Remaining Work) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.BoardLane (Board Lane) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.BoardColumnDone (Board Column Done) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.BoardColumn (Board Column) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Tags (Tags) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.RelatedLinkCount (Related Link Count) | 0
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.History (History) |
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Description (Description) | TFS 2013 - Work Item Id: <a href="http://<REDACTED>/_workitems#_a=edit&amp;id=1268&amp;triage=true">1268</a><br><br><p>Made footer height smaller to remove extra space.<br></p>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.CreatedBy (Created By) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.CreatedDate (Created Date) | 07/07/2017 16:51:28
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.WorkItemType (Work Item Type) | Task
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AssignedTo (Assigned To) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Reason (Reason) | Completed
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.ChangedBy (Changed By) | Migration
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Rev (Rev) | 3
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Watermark (Watermark) | 1118
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AuthorizedDate (Authorized Date) | 10/15/2020 09:09:19
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.State (State) | Closed
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Title (Title) | Footer Height Fix
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AuthorizedAs (Authorized As) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AreaId (Area ID) | 19
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Id (ID) | 107
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.ChangedDate (Changed Date) | 10/15/2020 09:09:19
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.RevisedDate (Revised Date) | 01/01/9999 00:00:00
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AreaPath (Area Path) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.NodeName (Node Name) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.AttachedFileCount (Attached File Count) | 0
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.HyperLinkCount (Hyperlink Count) | 1
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.CommentCount (Comment Count) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.RemoteLinkCount (Remote Link Count) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.Parent (Parent) | null
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.TeamProject (Team Project) | <REDACTED>
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.ExternalLinkCount (External Link Count) | 1
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.IterationId (Iteration ID) | 25
[09:09:19 INF] [                Task][Complete:     1/16][sid:   683|Rev:  2][tid:  null | System.IterationPath (Iteration Path) | <REDACTED>\Release 1\Sprint 1
[09:09:19 ERR] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.UnexpectedErrorException: TF237121: Cannot complete the operation. An unexpected error occurred.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SaveWorkItems(WorkItem[] workitems, Boolean bulk, SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel.TfsObjectModelExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Extensions.cs:line 55
   at MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel.Enrichers.WorkItemLinkEnricher.CreateExternalLink(ExternalLink sourceLink, WorkItemData target) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Enrichers\WorkItemLinkEnricher.cs:line 149
   at MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel.Enrichers.WorkItemLinkEnricher.Enrich(WorkItemData sourceWorkItemLinkStart, WorkItemData targetWorkItemLinkStart) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Enrichers\WorkItemLinkEnricher.cs:line 65
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItemLinks(IWorkItemMigrationClient sourceStore, IWorkItemMigrationClient targetStore, WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, WorkItemData targetWorkItem) in
D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 491
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, WorkItemData targetWorkItem, Int32 current) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 589
[09:09:19 INF] EmbededImagesRepairEnricher: Fixing HTML field attachemtnts for work item 107 from <REDACTED> to <REDACTED>
[09:09:20 ERR] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.UnexpectedErrorException: TF237121: Cannot complete the operation. An unexpected error occurred.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SaveWorkItems(WorkItem[] workitems, Boolean bulk, SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel.TfsObjectModelExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Extensions.cs:line 55
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItem(WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, Int32 retryLimit, Int32 retrys) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 409
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.UnexpectedErrorException: TF237121: Cannot complete the operation. An unexpected error occurred.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SaveWorkItems(WorkItem[] workitems, Boolean bulk, SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel.TfsObjectModelExtensions.SaveToAzureDevOps(WorkItemData context) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\Extensions.cs:line 55
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItem(WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, Int32 retryLimit, Int32 retrys) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 409
[09:09:20 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.UnexpectedErrorException: TF237121: Cannot complete the operation. An unexpected error occurred.

Technical information (for administrator):
Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unrecognized Resource link: Link Name: Fixed in Changeset Link Uri: vstfs:///Git/Commit/4238adc1-9b12-4722-a6d9-5dce4420157e%2f167a3457-c87e-41c9-9678-3685bafced8b%2f7c5d947259d347770c812c688698474e3ca3fc79
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ProcessWorkItem(WorkItemData sourceWorkItem, Int32 retryLimit, Int32 retrys) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 454
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 133
   at MigrationTools.Engine.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\Engine\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 45
[09:09:20 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[09:09:20 INF] Application is shutting down...
[09:09:20 INF] Terminating: Application forcebly closed.
[09:09:20 INF] Application Ending
[09:09:20 INF] The application ran in 00:00:25.1964754 and finished at 10/15/2020 09:09:20
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no way to skip link types that did not exist until a helpful PR from @TwitchBronBron was added to the tool.

v11.6.6 will not skip link types that are not available on the target.